# titanium iOS navbar styling

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I took over a project for a client, and the code given to me seems to have a broken navbar, or at least the styling is not correct. The buttons do work, just they're not styled properly. I'm unsure as where to begin to attempt to style this correctly.. I'll take someone out to dinner if they can point me in the right direction. I'm about to go crazy!

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: may be you can exposed some of the styling code then more easier for others to help

Comment: any chance that the code is designed for iOS 6 and you now running it on iOS 7?

Comment: That's a possibility. I'm downloading iOS 6 SDK now to test. Here's some of the code. https://github.com/kevinchandler/tickets

Comment: YES. That was it. I ran it with 6.1 simulator and it works like a charm. My next question is if I push it to the app store, will anyone with iOS 7 experience the same issue I had? I assume they will.. What exactly changed from 6 > 7 that's causing this issue, so i'm able to adjust accordingly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this migration guide for shifting app to iOS7

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_7_Migration_Guide

Thanks